# What are some techniques or Frameworks to secure username and password credentials in Selenium Web Automation Testing?

Tags: c#, authentication, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm using selenium web driver for my web page automation. The website on which I want to run test automation has an authentication page where I need to enter username and password. So I have just used `sendkeys()` to enter both username and password.*Writing such credentials as plain texts in source code is not a good practice*
 **Are there some programming libraries to send the encrypted texts as through the automation rather than username and password strings?**

Answer (score 1):

No when you are sending username and password to the login form in selenium it must not be encrypted it has to be the same you do manually.

However if you dont want to keep the username and password as plain strings you can put that in a App.config file.But this will let anyone to see the credentials who has access to the binaries.

But if you want the credentials to be more secure you can use below options

**Option 1**

When ever you start your selenium web driver test ask for username and password to be entered as an argument for C# console application. So that you dont have to store username and password anywhere

**ex:**
**myseleniumtest.exe 'username' 'password'**

1. Create an xml or json file or event text file in the solution and store your username and password
2. Right click the file and change the **Build Action** property to Embedded Resource
   [ Note: This will make the file to be embedded in the exe. So even if some one has access to the binaries they wont be able to find the credentials]
3. Access the content of the file in run time using below code.

**Sample Code**

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            const string resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";
            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        // Find username and password
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add the links for each idea you mentioned?

Comment: @TechJhola Im Sorry, What links are you expecting ?